# Who used Izanagi first?

Tags: naruto

I have been asked a question I can not seem to figure out regarding who used Izanagi first. I first thought it was Rai Uchiha, but when I give that answer, many stated that I am wrong.

Who used Izanagi first?

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site about anime & manga. Just a friendly advice in case you don't know, this is site is a bit different than traditional forums. Consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works, and enjoy~

Answer (score 5):

*Multiple* hours of confusion later:

## True answer

"According to Itachi, there was a point in time where members of the clan abused the abilities granted by Izanagi, instead simply casting the technique as a means of escaping the undesirable results of their actions. Whilst this resulted in little issue if only one person were using Izanagi, if there were two or more casters, they would begin to fight amongst each other over personally favourable outcomes. Thus, as dōjutsu users were unlikely to succumb to ocular genjutsu, Izanami was created as a method to reprimand such clansmen, as well as save them from their own arrogance. By imprisoning them within an unalterable loop of events, the victim was forced to accept the reality they had created if they ever wished to escape the illusion."
**- So really we don't know who the first person was.**

### Information about Izanagi:

Users:
 1. Danzo Shimura
 2. Madara Uchiha
3. Obito Uchiha
 (anime only:)
5.  Baru Uchiha
6.  Naka Uchiha
7. Rai Uchiha
 #: Unknown blokes/blokettes from Uchiha

Naka is described to have been "able to awaken his Mangekyō Sharingan and became obsessed with the technique Izanagi, which he used to kill some of his own clansmen." 
While "Baru was of its few members who were able to awaken the Sharingan in his youth" along with Rai who "was able to awaken the Sharingan in his youth".
We don't know the age of Madara when he was able to use Izanagi, even roughly, though he doesn't seem to have it in his youth?

**If you take the anime as definitive** it is between Baru and Rai who are the first, It is not clear which person used it first as they both awakened to the power in their "youth", no more description is given.

The Izanagi is a genjutsu that is cast on the user instead of others and is the most powerful amongst this type of genjutsu.

Izanagi can be used only by those with the genetic traits of the Sage of Six Paths. The Uchiha, descended from the Sage, are able to perform Izanagi with their Sharingan. Even with such an eye acting as a medium, gaining the power to temporarily control reality's flow as the user sees fit comes at a price; one has very limited reserves of time within a single eye for invoking this technique. This technique would normally be used for only the most dire of situations and for but a brief moment as after the Sharingan with which Izanagi was casted exceeds its limit, becoming powerless and permanently blind, though its sight and power can be restored by further evolving it into a Rinnegan. For this reason the Uchiha labelled it a kinjutsu.

Danzō Shimura, in an effort to make practical use of the technique, had ten Sharingan embedded into his right arm. To use Izanagi to its full potential, users must also have the genetic traits of the Senju, who are also descended from the Sage. Partially for this reason Danzō had some of Hashirama Senju's DNA transplanted into his arm, which extended the time span of each Sharingan's Izanagi to a minute, allowing him to use the technique for up to ten minutes in total, with breaks in between to conserve time. However, because Danzō is not an Uchiha, his chakra levels drop substantially every time he activates this technique.

(Since the timeline and plot is so muddled and tangled I could be wrong on the answer)

Sources:(There are a lot, its to help your eyes)

> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanagi
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uchiha_Clan_Downfall
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naka_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rai_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Baru_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/First_Shinobi_World_War
> http://narutofanon.wikia.com/wiki/Era_of_the_Warring_States
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Warring_States_Period
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Third_Shinobi_World_War
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izuna_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tajima_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shin_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanami
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hashirama_Senju
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Danz%C5%8D_Shimura
> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanagi_and_Izanami